# VBA Insert data in line below within a textbox

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to figure out how to display newly entered text from one userform text box to another userform text box in a new line below. Pretty much I want it to a multiline input. Here is the code I am using so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = TextBox1.Value & vbNewLine
End Sub
```

[image: image of what I am trying to accomplish]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.TextBox1.Value = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value & vbNewLine & UserForm2.TextBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: you should mark his answer as the proper answer to you question now ;)

Comment: @PaichengWu Sorry to reopen this question, is there any way of making the text start a multi line after the first input has been submitted? You can see in my above screenshot that Sample Text 1 is all the way in the top, in your provided code "Sample Text 1" skips a line. Thanks again for all your help

Comment: You can try to remove `vbNewLIne` and one `&` for my code.

Comment: @PaichengWu, I think it should be added, that the MultiLine property of the corresponding TextBoX object must be set to True. I have forgotten this on my first try and wondered why this solution did not work. This is just an improvement of the given solution, which is right.